# Error de tipo al ordenar, código no compilable

Tags: angular, typescript, ordenamiento

quiero ordenar un arreglo en Typescript, y este código que me solía funcionar sin problemas, me da error en la nueva version de Angular. (salte de 8 a 11)

y no entiendo la descripción de error, Alguien que me pueda ayudar a explicar el ¿porque de que el lintener me lo muestra como error?

```
    sortByAttribute<E>(array: Array<E>, attributeName: string): Array<E> {
        array.sort((a, b) => {
            if (a[attributeName] < b[attributeName]) return -1;
            else if (a[attributeName] > b[attributeName]) return 1;
            else return 0;
        });
        return array;
    }
```

Descripción del Error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que según tienes definido el genérico `E`, puede ser cualquier cosa: `string`, `number`, `object`,... Como el tipo de `E` es desconocido, pues no puede saber si va a tener índices o no.

Entiendo que `E` siempre va a ser un objeto en tu caso, por tanto puedes modificar el genérico para indicar esto de la siguiente manera:

```
sortByAttribute<E extends Record<string, any>>(...){
```

que es equivalente a:

```
sortByAttribute<E extends {[key:string]:any}>(...){
```

un saludo

Comment: Perfecto, ahora entendi, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Extendiendo la respuesta de @akotech que es totalmente válida a nivel conceptual, una aproximación más "type safe" sería la siguiente:

```
function sortByAttribute<E>(array: Array<E>, attributeName: keyof E): Array<E> {
  array.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[attributeName] < b[attributeName]) return -1;
    else if (a[attributeName] > b[attributeName]) return 1;
    else return 0;
  });
  return array;
}
```

En este caso no modificamos el genérico, si no que hacemos explícito que el parámetro `attributeName` debe obligatoriamente ser una `key` del objeto genérico utilizando [`keyof E`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html).

Un ejemplo de uso sería el siguiente:

```
interface Test {
  a: number
  b: number
  c: string
}

sortByAttribute([] as Test[], 'b');
```

Lo bueno de esta aproximación es que no podemos pasar cualquier valor al parámetro `attributeName`; Si intentamos pasar un atributo que no existe en el genérico, el compilador nos mostrará un error:

```
sortByAttribute([] as Test[], 'no-existe');
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
                               Argument of type '"no-existe"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Test'.(2345)
```

Si quieres experimentar, te dejo el [`playground de código`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgJygIQJ4EEpRowBGIUApgDwCiAfABQCGaaj2AXIri2zbQDSJGBIqQoA5RgFtynANblscYImoBKTt1bY+iAN4AoREJ7YAdKgz0mg4msQBeWvqPG3MFUwDawwiTLkkjIAuoiUiMQ+Iv4S0uTB9mjkUCBoSAC0AIwA3K5uiOQANsjkiB6I3r6iAUHxiM6RVTGBcQmISSlpiDl5bkUl7cmpSAAMucYAvmrjg51IzNq5EwYGMGAUaMCMEKUAKuTIUC7GjJxgIFLE5GiuxGcXVzfGEJyHRGAA5gbLBpZYeNExOR6F5QoxkIh9odQYIAOSMWHTFZAA).